# How to open a file in windows asynchronously

Tags: .net, windows, file, winapi, asynchronous

Is there a way to open a file in Windows asynchronously? The CreateFile API function has only FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED which allows for further asynchronous reads and writes. Nonetheless, the opening of the file seems to be synchronous. Given, it has to access the file system (and potentially perform expensive IO operations), it may be a potential blocker.

This is actually an underlying question to, whether it is possible to open a file in .NET asynchronously (as FileStream ctor cannot be awaited). But the question is rather pointless if there is no way to do it in the OS.

Comment: How would you propose [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) to report errors (or even pass a valid handle back), if there were a way to call it asynchronously? The second part of your question doesn't make any sense. Of course you can always implement an asynchronous framework call on top of a call, that isn't itself asynchronous. The UWP, for example, provides only asynchronous calls to open a file, even though it executes strictly synchronous API calls.

Comment: @IInspectable - The same way any other overlapped operation in windows works. I.e. in the overlapped structure you would pass a callback function which would return a handle or error code. Similarly to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364052.aspx
Re second part, that's a bit off-topic. Of course it's better to have "fake" async api which uses threads under the hoods. Nonetheless, it deters the benefit of async flow unless the whole chain works this way. Just my opinion...

Comment: *"Nonetheless, it deters the benefit of async flow unless the whole chain works this way."* - So then, go ahead, ditch .NET and move on to UWP, where **everything** works this way. Or use the [Parallel Patterns Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx), so that you can wrap any synchronous call into an asynchronous interface. Or C++' [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) for that matter. At the end of the day, someone will have to spin up a thread, or use an existing thread pool thread to implement asynchronicity.

Comment: @Elephantik - "The same way any other overlapped operation in windows works" - any api for create/open file (`CreateFile -> ZwOpenFile, ZwCreateFile -> IoCreateFile -> ObOpenObjectByName`) not take in parameters apc callback function or event. and because handle yet not created - no bind to some IOCP - so no way, even if use low level api, even if from kernel mode.

Comment: @IInspectable: `At the end of the day, someone will have to spin up a thread, or use an existing thread pool thread to implement asynchronicity.` No. Asynchrony is not dependent on threads.

Comment: @StephenCleary: That's true, or not, depending on how you look at it. Asynchronicity can be implemented by setting up interrupt handlers, and offloading the work to dedicated hardware (like the DMA circuitry). Arguably, this dedicated hardware operates on its own thread of execution (although this isn't anything like an OS thread, and I'll admit, that I didn't think of it that way).

Comment: It would be relatively simple.  Just have a CreateFileHandle call which returns the handle instantly, then use it in an Open or Create File call to create the underlying object.  MS conflated the concept of creation of the handle with creation of the underlying file.  Sockets work similarly.  Call socket() then call connect().  Some file creation can take a long time to fail, especially over network paths.  Making it synchronous only creates massive bottleneck problems.  It's happening async in the kernel anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way in user mode to create/open a file asynchronously. Even if the driver returns `STATUS_PENDING` for [`IRP_MJ_CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548630(v=vs.85).aspx), the system will be waiting in this case until the driver completes the `IRP` before it returns control from one of the create/open file functions.

Only if we are in kernel mode it's possible, if you yourself format [`IRP_MJ_CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548630(v=vs.85).aspx) and send it to the driver. But even in this case the drivers will almost always handle [`IRP_MJ_CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548630(v=vs.85).aspx) synchronously.

---

for API be asynchronous - must be some way notify caller when operation finished

windows used 3 ways for this

1. some callback routine in parameters, usually APC (`PIO_APC_ROUTINE`)
   which called when operation finished
2. some Event in parameters, when operation finished, Event set in
   signal state.
3. file handle, used in api call, is binded for some IOCP. when
   operation finished packet is queued to IOCP. (we remove this packet later by call [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) (`ZwRemoveIoCompletion`) or [`KeRemoveQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549605(v=vs.85).aspx)

3) is impossible in our case because file handle yet not created, so it can not be bind to any IOCP. about 1) and 2) let looks for file open/create api signatures:

in user mode the lowest level api for open/create file is [`ZwOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ZwCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424(v=vs.85).aspx). [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) is shell over `ZwCreateFile`. in kernel mode `NtOpenFile` -> `NtCreateFile` -> [`IoCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548418(v=vs.85).aspx) -> [`IoCreateFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548283(v=vs.85).aspx) even - [`IoCreateFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548283(v=vs.85).aspx) (the most low level api for create file) - have no Event or [Apc] callback parameter - so not asynchronously. [`IoCreateFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548283(v=vs.85).aspx) call `ObOpenObjectByName` (not documented, but exported routine) - here also no 1) or 2) parameters - again this is synchronous by design api

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to open a file in Windows asynchronously?

No, unfortunately. Interestingly, at the device driver level, all such interaction is asynchronous (or *can* be asynchronous, at least). But that is not exposed at the Win32 level.

The UWP asynchronous file-open APIs are just fake-asynchronous APIs - they delegate synchronous work to the thread pool. They're not truly asynchronous. You'll need to do the same thing if you want non-blocking file-opens on .NET (which is often desirable if you're dealing with files over a network share).

Comment: "at the device driver level, all such interaction is asynchronous (or can be asynchronous, at least). " - only if direct send IRP_MJ_CREATE - *can* be asynchronous. even `IoCreateFile` or `ObOpenObjectByName` - synchronous api

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the CreateFile mechanism conflates the concept of creation of the handle with the concept of associating it with a named file on a disk somewhere.

whereas with sockets, you call a function to create a socket handle, then associate it (bind it) with an endpoint (effectively a name).

MS could have done something similar for files, where you would allocate the handle first unbound, then associate it with a completion port, then asynchronously request association with a file path, which could then be signalled upon completion.

Because face it, underlying all the network redirector stuff is asynchronous, and all the management of IRPs by the IO manager are as well.

It's crazy that after 30 years, there's still no way to do this in Windows.