# Is FileReader.ReadAsync truly async?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, winapi, .net-core, windows-runtime

So recently I was reading Richter's book *CLR via C#*. It is about .NET Framework 4.5 or something, and there he states that `FileReader.ReadAsync` is not truly asynchronous, it is actually just an async wrapper over synchronous `win32` API. I am not a .NET Framework developer, I use .NET Core. So I have a few questions:

1. How bad for app scaling is the fact that it wraps sync functions with something like Task.Run ?
2. Is the behavior described above fixed in .NET Core? If I say `FileReader.ReadAsync`, will it read asynchronously?
3. What's the point of having that `FileOptions.Asynchronous` if you can determine whether I want operations to be sync or async based on methods I call e.g `Read` or `ReadAsync`?
4. Why not use WinRT for async reading/opening if WinRT provides that and `win32` doesnt?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this were true.

Comment: Richters sub-chapter "Some operations should be synchronous" or something like that. Approximately 815th page

Comment: and related to it "FileStream problems"

Comment: I have a translated version, so this might not be the same as it is a translation of translation: "From an application's perspective, it looks like asynchronous execution of operations, but actually FileStream class emulates asynchrony with additional thread that only spends resources and reduces performance"

Comment: also consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41302070/9796873) post. Opening file in windows is **always** synchronous

Comment: @МаркПавлович - and so what ? you ask about readfile. you need re read "FileStream-Specific Issues" from begin

Comment: @RbMm oh yes, you might be right. So this only applies to FileStreams to which FileOptions.Asynchronous wasn't passed?

Comment: again - re read what written in *FileStream-Specific Issues*

Comment: *When you create a FileStream object, you get to specify whether you want to communicate using
synchronous or asynchronous operations via the FileOptions.Asynchronous flag (which is
equivalent to calling the Win32 CreateFile function and passing into it the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag). If you do not specify this flag, Windows performs all operations against
the file synchronously. Of course, you can still call FileStream’s ReadAsync method...*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202270/discussion-between---and-rbmm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FileStream.ReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.readasync?view=netframework-4.8) always asynchronously reads from file from application level view (in sense call not blocked at this point and just return control to user code).

but are this is truly or emulated asynchronous I/O - depend from [`FileOptions.Asynchronous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions?view=netframework-4.8) option: from [Using Async for File Access (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access)

> this option causes asynchronous I/O to occur at the operating system
>   level. By using this option, you can avoid blocking a ThreadPool
>   thread in many cases

this is answer for

> What's the point of having that FileOptions.Asynchronous

and from book

> When you create a FileStream object, you get to specify whether you
>   want to communicate using synchronous or asynchronous operations via
>   the **FileOptions.Asynchronous** flag (which is equivalent to calling the
>   Win32 **CreateFile** function and passing into it the **FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED**
>   flag). If you do not specify this flag, Windows performs all
>   operations against the file synchronously. Of course, you can still
>   call FileStream’s **ReadAsync** method, and to your application, it looks
>   as if the operation is being performed asynchronously, but internally,
>   the FileStream class uses another thread to emulate asynchronous
>   behavior; use of this thread is wasteful and hurts performance. On the
>   other hand, you can create a FileStream object by specifying the
>   **FileOptions.Asynchronous** flag. Then you can call FileStream’s Read
>   method to perform a synchronous operation. Internally, the FileStream
>   class emulates this behavior by starting an asynchronous operation and
>   then immediately puts the calling thread to sleep until the operation
>   is complete. This is also inefficient, but it is not as inefficient as
>   calling ReadAsync by using a FileStream constructed without the
>   **FileOptions.Asynchronous** flag

so here stated that FileStream class uses another thread to emulate asynchronous behavior only in case you **not specify** `FileOptions.Asynchronous` flag .

> Why not use WinRT for async reading/opening if WinRT provides that and
>   win32 doesnt?

winRT internal anyway call win32 (or native) api.