# How to open file in Windows as soon as it's unlocked?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, window

In my program I call ReadDirectoryChangesW to listen for file events in a given directory. The problem is some events (e.g. `FILE_ACTION_ADDED`) are signaled when the file is *opened*, not *closed*. This means the file will be locked by other process for some unspecified amount of time and `CreateFileW` will be returning an error.

The question is: how do I open the file when the other process is done with it? I can tolerate race conditions (e.g. some other process manages to delete the file after it's closed, but before I open it), but I'd like to avoid busy waiting.

Options I see/considered so far:

- Asynchronous `CreateFileW`. That would be an ideal solution, but it's not possible - all user-space APIs for opening a file are synchronous by design (see a [great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41302070/4259190)).
- Listening for `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS`. This **almost** works - notification on close is sent only when the other process wrote some bytes to the file.
- I also found some resources on kernel filter drivers, which can detect file close event. Probably works, but seems a bit too complex.
- Busy loop continuously calling `CreateFileW` until it succeeds. Overutilizes the CPU, but is the only thing that actually works. I'm worried I'm stuck with this approach.